# Select rows from one table and add to new table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a new table called 'quiz' and insert specified rows from an existing questions table into the quiz table. I want to be able choose which questions to include on a given quiz, hence the IN (13,14,15). I also want to create a new table on the fly instead of using a preexisting one. I am trying to use the query below but it doesn't work.

```
CREATE TABLE `quiz` 
  ( 
     ID           INT(11), 
     question     MEDIUMTEXT, 
     output       MEDIUMTEXT, 
     functionname TINYTEXT, 
     p_args       TINYTEXT, 
     r_args       TINYTEXT, 
     hint         MEDIUMTEXT, 
     score        INT(255), 
     PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
  );

SELECT from * `questions` where id IN (13, 14, 15);
```

This is what my questions table looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OULZn.jpg

I have been at it for a 2 hours and I have tried a number of things but it doesn't work. I am beginning to think isn't the correct approach here.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "it doesn't work" part ?

Comment: It doesn't create a table with with the given questions. With some tinkering I can create a quiz table but it includes all the questions instead of the ones specified.

Comment: That's a typo - if you looked to the error mysql gives, you would have found the problem those `"2 hours"` ago.

Comment: I tried using the query directly on mysql server and got the generic 1064 error.

Answer (score 3):

As long as all your columns match up

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE ID IN (13, 14, 15)
```

should fix it

Answer (score 1):

your select query is

```
SELECT FROM * `questions` WHERE ID IN (13, 14, 15)
```

it's wrong

use

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` WHERE ID IN (13, 14, 15)
```

Comment: Wow thanks it worked, so stupid of me that I checked everything but not the simple syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query is

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `quiz`(ID int(11), question mediumtext, output mediumtext, functionname tinytext, p_args tinytext, r_args tinytext, hint mediumtext, score int(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID)) SELECT FROM * `questions` WHERE ID IN (13, 14, 15)"
```

instead use

```
  $sql = "CREATE TABLE `quiz`(ID int(11), question mediumtext, output mediumtext, functionname tinytext, p_args tinytext, r_args tinytext, hint mediumtext, score int(255), PRIMARY KEY (ID)) SELECT * from `questions`WHERE ID IN (13, 14, 15)"
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you got full access to the MySQL server, simply dump the table, edit the dump file by notepad++. By editing you'll change the name of the table and will remove the rows you don't like. After that lunch the edited file and voila.